Number of Active Validators on Sepolia Testnet?
Any idea how can I get the number of active validator nodes on the sepolia testnet ?
The only thing I could find is the beaconcha explorer ( https://sepolia.beaconcha.in/), and it states 1776 active nodes.
Is there another way to fetch this information ?
Thank you.
